# Measuring time of multithreaded algorithm without counting waiting on condition variable and stuff

Tags: linux, multithreading, time

Is there some way to measure real (wall) time of **multithreaded** algorithm, without counting waiting on condition variables and stuff? I do not want to count time of creating threads and joining them and waiting for each other. Just time when program actually is executing.

EDIT:

Actually... i need to measure also waiting on conditions, but i dont want to count time of getting thread ready or getting it to sleep. Just execution of algorithm and waiting for other threads. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Take the time at the start and and end of thread ?

Comment: Well that's not enough. In thread there are many situations where it waits(i use condition variable in c++) for another thread to complete part of calculation. And i believe that when it waits on condition variable it is stopped and then later started again. And i think, that these operations take some time. And this time i dont want to count to my total time.